# Terraform nested dynamic block: Unsupported block type

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am trying to do something like below.

```
  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    content {
      host_path = lookup(volume.value, "host_path", null)
      name      = volume.value.name

      dynamic "efs_volume" {
        for_each = var.efs_volumes
        content {
          name = efs_volume.value.name
          efs_volume_configuration {
            file_system_id     = efs_volume.value.file_system_id
            root_directory     = efs_volume.value.root_directory
            transit_encryption = efs_volume.value.transit_encryption != "ENABLED" ? "" : "ENABLED"
            dynamic "authorization_config" {
              for_each = efs_volume.value.access_point_id != "" ? [1] : []
              content {
                access_point_id = volume.value.access_point_id
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Its giving me,

> Error: Unsupported block type
>
> Blocks of type "efs_volume" are not expected here

Can anyone point me what is wrong here? I am using terraform 0.12.24.

Please note, I know that "authorization_config" still not supported by AWS provider, I hope the feature will be coming soon as I have seen the github pull request. Hence, I'm preparing my code compatibility. Basically, what I need is to mount both host and EFS volumes into my ECS task definition.

### EDIT

I updated the code as you said.

````
  dynamic "volume" {
    for_each = var.volumes
    content {
      host_path = lookup(volume.value, "host_path", null)
      name      = volume.value.name

      dynamic "efs_volume_configuration" {
        for_each = lookup(volume.value, "efs_volume_configuration", [])
        content {
          file_system_id = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "file_system_id", null)
          root_directory = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "root_directory", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }```

Now the problem is, 

> efs_volume_configuration

getting added to each volume block. Which actually need to be null.

```      + volume { # forces replacement
          + host_path = "/var/run"
          + name      = "docker-sock-folder"

          + efs_volume_configuration {}
        }
      + volume { # forces replacement
          + host_path = "/var/run/docker/netns"
          + name      = "docker-netns"

          + efs_volume_configuration {}
        }
      + volume { # forces replacement
          + name = "efs_share"

          + efs_volume_configuration {
              + file_system_id = "fs-xxxxxx"
              + root_directory = "/"
            }
        }
````

EDIT

Here is my varaibles..

```
  type = list(object({
    name      = string
    host_path = string
    efs_volume_configuration = list(object({
      file_system_id = string
      root_directory = string
    }))
  }))
  description = "Task volume definitions as list of configuration objects"
  default = [
    {
      "name" : "data-folder",
      "host_path" : "/var/lib/data",
      "efs_volume_configuration" = [
        {
          "file_system_id" : "",
          "root_directory" : ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "docker-sock-folder",
      "host_path" : "/var/run",
      "efs_volume_configuration" = [
        {
          "file_system_id" : "",
          "root_directory" : ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" : "efs_share",
      "host_path" : null,
      "efs_volume_configuration" = [
        {
          "file_system_id" : "fs-xxxxxx",
          "root_directory" : "/"
        }
      ]
    }

....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ecs task definition resource efs_volume is not a supported argument. If you looking for a fully working module, perhaps module I have written that works well and is published to terraform registry may help. https://github.com/umotif-public/terraform-aws-ecs-fargate-task-definition/blob/master/main.tf#L157

To use efs volumes you can define following dynamic block:

```
dynamic "volume" {
for_each = var.volume
content {
  name      = volume.value.name
  host_path = lookup(volume.value, "host_path", null)

  dynamic "docker_volume_configuration" {
    for_each = lookup(volume.value, "docker_volume_configuration", [])
    content {
      scope         = lookup(docker_volume_configuration.value, "scope", null)
      autoprovision = lookup(docker_volume_configuration.value, "autoprovision", null)
      driver        = lookup(docker_volume_configuration.value, "driver", null)
      driver_opts   = lookup(docker_volume_configuration.value, "driver_opts", null)
      labels        = lookup(docker_volume_configuration.value, "labels", null)
    }
  }

  dynamic "efs_volume_configuration" {
    for_each = lookup(volume.value, "efs_volume_configuration", [])
    content {
      file_system_id = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "file_system_id", null)
      root_directory = lookup(efs_volume_configuration.value, "root_directory", null)
    }
  }
}
```

In this case efs_volume_configuration is a support block. Once you have that in your module, you can pass in efs config in the following way:

```
module "ecs-task-definition" {
...
  volume = [
    {
      name = "efs-html",
      efs_volume_configuration = [
        {
          "file_system_id" : "efs_id",
          "root_directory" : "/usr/share/nginx"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Important: you need at least version v2.64.0 of terraform aws provider.

Comment: I added an example how you can pass the variables into your module. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for you support. Could you please check the my EDIT section. After changing my code, now problem is ```efs_volume_configuration {}``` getting added to each volume, which actually need to be null.

Comment: I don’t believe it is an issue. It shouldn’t fail.

Comment: It is failing ```- missing required field, RegisterTaskDefinitionInput.Volumes[0].EfsVolumeConfiguration.FileSystemId.```

Comment: I just tried the same configuration and I can't replicated this behaviour. I also tested the same solution with my module https://github.com/umotif-public/terraform-aws-ecs-fargate-task-definition and I am not getting this. I am using terraform v0.12.26 and provider version v2.67.0

Comment: I just upgraded to the same versions. Still issue is same. When you running tf plan, you also getting ```+ efs_volume_configuration {}```?

Comment: I'm just suspecting, if I'm messing with my variables. Hence, just posted it for your reference. Could you please check my last EDIT.

Comment: I see, if you not using efs_volume_configuration just remove it from your variables.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using it. but it was at the end of the variables section, just updated the variables in the EIDT section.

Comment: for volumes `data-folder` and `docker-sock-folder` remove efs_volume_configuration

Comment: Yeah! that did the trick. thank you so much. You have saved a lot of time of mine. to be honest have spent more than 8 hours on this entire thing.

Comment: Before, I close this, once quick question from you if possible to answer here. Do you see that ```"file_system_id" : "fs-xxxxxx"``` under my variable. I want to pass it from the output value from another module as I have three environments to use the same code. Do you mind me to give me a clue how to do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should create efs volume either as part of your module or data source the efs volume and then reference efs id. It should not be hardcoded in your vars

Comment: Actually, I'm creating it as part of same tf call and I can grab it from ```module.efs.id```, but my problem is, how to inject it into this dynamic block. Because, I'm injecting this entire ```volume``` variable into child module.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. In fact, I could pass it as a different variable. Sorry for asking dummy question. Thank you so much for your great support.